# Bootstrap 3 modals not working on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 for my project but cannot seem to get the modals to work correctly when loading remote content.

My "application" layout is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TestBootstrap</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I have two views, one is index and the other is show

index contains the following information:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="/modal/show">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Show contains the following:

```
<div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Find me in app/views/modal/show.html.erb</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
```

For some odd reason I get the modal displayed without a background when adding the "remote-data" attribute.

[image]
I have tried removing "turbo_links" but it has been futile. This only seem to happen in rails though, as I have tried a similar example in jsfiddle and it works fine!
Please see http://jsfiddle.net/6X2zb/

Please help and thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried using the `:branch3` of `twitter-bootstrap-rails`?

Comment: Hi kobaltz, thanks for replying. I am not using the "twitter-boostrap-rails" gem. Instead I am loading bootstrap 3 in my application layout through  
"<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>" cdn from http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: I just traid using the "twitter-boostrap-rails" gem

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails',
:git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', :branch => "bootstrap3"

but attempt was futile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out what the issue was from [Bootstrap 3 with remote Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal?rq=1)

Turns out I was missing the surrounding

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">

   ... contents ...

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit this wall just yesterday.  I wound up using bootstrap-modal instead, which provides a patch for bootstrap 3.

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap 3 specific examples:

http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html

Here's the rails example

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/wiki/Ruby-on-Rails----AJAX-Modal-Example

Comment: Thanks for responding and the resources. I'm still wondering why it's happening in the first place though :/. If I can't figure it out I will most likely make use of bootstrap-modal. The resources here are more than sufficient to get me going, great work !

Comment: Hey trh, I've been trying to make use of bootstrap-modal but it seems it injects content into .modal-body rather than .modal-content (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9318). Whenever I try to use the example from jsfiddle along with bootstrap-modal I get 2 stacked models since content is being injected into .modal-body :(. Any suggestions ?