# link_to modal popup with do loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to figure this out for a day or two. In my index view I have a list-group populated with "task" entries. For each of these I would like to link_to a modal, preferably a partial or the show.html.erb view, but I am having trouble figuring out how to a) either pass the `task` to the modal or b) pass the `task` to a partial or the show.html.erb view. I am using twitter-bootstrap.

This code produces this error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

For this line in the modal:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
```

my tasks_controller.rb index method:

```
def index
  @tasks = current_user.projects.find(session[:current_project]).tasks.where(:project_id => session[:current_project])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:notice] = "You have no tasks."
    redirect_to action: :show, controller: :projects, id: session[:current_project]
end
```

my index.html.erb:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <div class="row" id="task-row">
      <%= link_to "#myModal", :id => task.id, :data => {:toggle=>"modal"}, :remote => true, :class=> "list-group-item" do %>
        <span class="col-md-11">
          <h3 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= task.title %></h3>
          <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= task.description.capitalize unless task.nil? %></p>
        </span>
        <span class="col-md-1">
          <p><%= task.priority %></p>
        </span>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Rails: Edit record in Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689846/edit-record-in-bootstrap-modal/18690756#18690756).

It should explain how to render a partial from show.html.erb inside a modal from index.html.erb