# Rails: Different modal for each link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I have this structure in my view:

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li> <%= category.name %> <a href='#'>Edit</a> </li> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to popup a modal when I click "Edit" and in this modal to place a form for editing corresponding category. I want to avoid to generate a modal for each element from loop and I want to have a generic modal and call it each time, with specific parameters. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure , you just need to pass category id  to modal and you ready to go .

Comment: How can I do this? Can you explain me please? I am beginner in rails :(

Comment: Same question on stack overflolw. [Edit Record in  Modal][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689846/edit-record-in-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use remote true for js response

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
     <li> <%= category.name %><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category), remote: true %> </li> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
<div class='modal-fade' id="edit-modal"></div>
```

create one partial page _edit.html.erb
write bootstarp modal structure and edit form and in form write remote: true

```
 eg. <%= form_for @category, remote: true do %>......<%end%>
```

create edit.js file and write as below

```
$('#edit-modal').html("<%= j render 'edit' %>");
$('#edit-modal').modal('show');
```

and create one more file create.js

```
$('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a remote link:

```
link_to "edit", edit_category_path(category), class: "btn btn-mini", remote: true
```

Then in your views, add a edit.js.erb file:

```
$("#myModal").html("<%= j render "new"%>");
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

and change your edit.html and new.html files to _new.html and edit.html