# Rendering a simple_form inside an each loop, rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating a shopping list app, each user has a list and each list has many items.

On the show page, I'm iterating over a users list and showing each item in the list and printing out the item name, description & a link to update the item.

The problem is, the update form always uses the first item in the each iteration instead of its assigned item.

I can have a list with 5 rows of items and the update link for each item will always populate with first item in the row.

I'm new to rails so any help with this would be appreciated!

**Routes**

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  patch 'items/pick/:id', to: "items#pick", as: :pick

  devise_for :users
  root to: 'lists#index'
  resources :lists do
    resources :items
  end
end
```

**List controller**

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists = List.all
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end
end
```

**Item controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list])
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.list_id = @list.id
    @item.user_id = current_user.id
    if @item.save!
      redirect_to list_path(@list), notice: "Item added to list."
    else
      render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update(venue_params)
      redirect_to venue_path(@venue)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    redirect_to list_path(params[:list_id])
  end

  def pick
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if item.buyer.nil?
      item.buyer = current_user.id
    else
      item.buyer = nil
    end
    item.save!
    redirect_to lists_path
  end

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:item_name, :description, :link, :price)
  end
end
```

**Show page - update form rendered as the last item in the each loop**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
      <h2>Hello <%= current_user.first_name %> </h2>
      <p>Welcome to Listy, the new home of your gift lists</p>
      <h4 class="mb-3">Manage: <%= link_to "Family lists", lists_path %></h4>


        <div class="card p-3 mb-3">
            <p><%= @list.title %> ID: <%= @list.id  %> </p>
            <% @list.items.sort.each do |item| %>
              <div class="list-flex">
                <div class="item_name"><%= item.item_name %></div>
                <div class="description-show-page"><%= item.description %></div>
                <div class="link"><%= render "lists/partial/update_item", list: @list, item: item %></div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>

      <%= render "lists/partial/add_item" %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update partial**

```
<a type="" class="gray" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal">
  <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update item</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <%= simple_form_for [@list, item] do |f| %>
          <h2> <%= item.id %></h2>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'list', @list.id %>
          <%= f.input :item_name %>
          <%= f.input :description %>
          <%= f.input :link %>
          <%= f.input :price %>
          <%= f.submit "Add Item", class: "btn btn-outline-primary" %>
        <% end %>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Image of list on the show page, note the update links**
[image]

**Every update link renders the form using the first item in the list, 90 is the list ID**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams a classic edit modal scenario

When you load the page, you render only one modal.

You have 3 records that mean, you need 3 modals

**OR** you can dynamically create a new modal like
[Rails: Edit record in Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689846/rails-edit-record-in-bootstrap-modal)