# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I've been trying to implement a modal on my site that dynamically loads the content using an ajax call.

I stumbled across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595243/get-ajax-data-and-display-on-bootstrap-modal), which showed this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6o7atqd3/1/), which would suit my needs perfectly after a little modification.

The demo works perfectly on JSFiddle, but inside my dev environment is spitting out the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tracing it back to my script it is saying that htmlData is undefined, but it is defined right above it?

Script that runs the call:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var infoModal = $('#myModal');
    $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/api/menu-item/'+$(this).data('id'),
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(data){
                fakeResponse = {"id":4,"menu_category_id":446,"name":"kunzereichert","description":"Dolores impedit ut doloribus et a et aut.","price":"999.99","created_at":"2015-04-10 05:55:23","updated_at":"2015-04-10 05:55:23"}
;
                var htmlData = '<ul><li>';
                htmlData += fakeResponse.name;
                htmlData += '</li></ul>';
                infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlData;
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I'm not very fluent with javascript, so would appreciate any help with why I am getting this error. I am just trying to test loading some information from a JSON response to then display inside the modal.

If there is a better way to do this then I am open to suggestions to!

**Edit: this is the HTML code for my page**

```
@extends('sbadmin')

@section('content')

<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">

    <h1><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Staff</h1>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach ($staff as $employee)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $employee->first_name }} {{ $employee->last_name }}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="{{ $employee->id }}">Disable</button><a href="{{ url('staff/regularhours/' . $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Staff Details</a>  <a href="{{ url('staff/regularhours/' . $employee->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Regular Hours</a></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    {!! $staff->render() !!}

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    var infoModal = $('#myModal');
    $('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/api/menu-item/'+$(this).data('id'),
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(data){
                fakeResponse = {"id":4,"menu_category_id":446,"name":"kunzereichert","description":"Dolores impedit ut doloribus et a et aut.","price":"999.99","created_at":"2015-04-10 05:55:23","updated_at":"2015-04-10 05:55:23"}
;
                var htmlData = '<ul><li>';
                htmlData += fakeResponse.name;
                htmlData += '</li></ul>';
                infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlData;
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

@endsection
```

Comment: `$('#myModal')` is a jQuery selector looking for a HTML element with an ID `myModal`, so you should make sure that element exists in your HTML. You might want to read up on the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function - you'll see that the `error` property is actually "A function to be called if the request fails." You'll probably want add (or replace error with) a `success` property to for when the request succeeds.

Comment: can you show your html? are you sure there is div with `id=modal-body` inside div `id=myModal`.

Comment: @MKA I have added the HTML code for my modal.

Comment: change `infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlData;` to `infoModal.find('.modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlData;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined" error is actually referring to the `infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0]` part and not the `htmlData` part.

So, you are getting this error because it is saying that `infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0]` does not exist. In the demo that you are using the code from, it has a `<div id="myModal"></div>` which relates to your `var infoModal = $('#myModal');`

Inside the div, is a `<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body"></div>`. This is what the `infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0]` is trying to locate. So, your error is saying that the element the `find()` is looking for doesn't exist and you are trying to set its innerHTML.

So, check your HTML and make sure you copied over the HTML from the demo or at least the `<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body"></div>` part of it.

**EDIT**

Your HTML shows that your element is `<div class="modal-body"></div>` but your call is `infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0]` which is looking for an ID of `modal-body`. Try changing it to this:
`infoModal.find('.modal-body')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: This solved it. I hadn't included `id="modal-body"` inside the modal-body. Such a simple mistake! Thanks Frank

Comment: Better would be `infoModal.find('.modal-body').html();`

Comment: No worries @James. We have all been there looking over code for hours and it turns out to be a simple fix.

Comment: @DelightedD0D That works too. Thanks for both of your help.

Comment: My bad, I meant `infoModal.find('#modal-body').html();`, using `.html()` since you're using jQuery already ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Use **modal-body** is Class Name but You Access by Id Name so 
You change this code

```
infoModal.find('#modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlData;
```

to

```
infoModal.find('.modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlData;
```

Or

```
$('.modal-body')html(htmlData);
```

this is working Fine

or add id name is **modal-body**