# Laravel HTML link to open Bootstrap modal and fetch data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to have a Laravel HTML link which opens up a Bootstrap modal on the same page and fetches data from an ID in the link. Similar to what happens when you click a tweet on Twitter.

At the minute, I can only get it to open up on a new page.

**blade.php:**

```
{!! Html::linkAction('ContentController@getImages', 'Screenshots', array($row->ID), array('class' => 'trigger')) !!}
```

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('screenshots/{id}', 'ContentController@getImages');
```

`screenshots/{id}` is a different page. I want to open the Bootstrap modal on the same page, which is `content/{year}/{category}`

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').on('click', function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');      
            }, 250));
            $(this).unbind('scroll');
        });
    });
});
```

I've tested this with a standard HTML link and it opens the Bootstrap modal fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 - How to load content in modal body via AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663555/bootstrap-3-how-to-load-content-in-modal-body-via-ajax)