# Passing a PHP variables to a modal window

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with data being displayed using a php foreach loop. I have successfully linked the Client_Code to a modal window, but I would like to somehow grab the the data for the client linked to that client code and then use that data in the modal window.

My loop looks like this

```
"<tr>
         <td><a class='btn btn-outline-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#large'>" . $rows['Client_Code'] . " </td></a>
         <td>" . $rows['firstname'] . " " . $rows['lastname'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['Service_Name'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['billingemail'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['Business_Name'] . "</td>
       </tr>";
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I have tried various solutions from this site. The most common seems to be using Ajax. Unfortunately I do not know js and I am finding this to be a bit tricky. Anyway to do this using just php?

Comment: If you want to do it without ajax, you have to create modal popup for each row. It's better to use Ajax.

Comment: Well there are 800+ rows and this number will keep growing so creating a modal for each row would be senseless. How do I go about using ajax so that I actually understand what I am doing

Comment: try this link it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663555/bootstrap-3-how-to-load-content-in-modal-body-via-ajax