# How do modals load content from external sources?

Tags: javascript, html

I see various modals (bootstrap etc.) have the ability to load in content from a URL.

What is the technology behind doing this, javascript? if so how does it work?

Comment: can you provide an example of an "external source"

Comment: Just a web page, like /products.html

Comment: it work with ajax request, same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255191/6390681)

Answer (score 3):

This is normally done with either:

- [a iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) in the modal container *or*
- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) / [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with the requested content being inserted into the DOM afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Yes they use JavaScript, you can do this in 2 ways.

One way is using an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) and the second isusing [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to load the data or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function