# pass multiple php variables to modal

Tags: php, jquery

i want to pass multiple `php` variables to my modal. this how I am passing my variables but i also want to pass `$idd` and $gift variable to the modal

```
$gift ="plasma";
$idd = 4;
$track = "ty67890iuoj":

<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySing<?php echo $track; ?>">View</a></li>

//modal
<div id="mySing<?php echo $track; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="text-center">Order Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <h3 class="text-center">Print Details</h3>
      <div class="text-center">
     <?php $notan = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('order_printd','trackingnumber',$track);             
            foreach($notan as $ron):?>
            <span style="padding-right: 5px;font-weight: 600;"><?php echo DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('name','print_type','print_type_id',$ron['print_type_id']);?></span>

     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its really inefficient pumping out a ton of dom which may never be used, why not use ajax instead? Picking up additional variables from `data-*` attributes?

Comment: how does it work @LawrenceCherone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663555/bootstrap-3-how-to-load-content-in-modal-body-via-ajax