# Bootstrap Modal - How to provide data from php (database)

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

This is probably very simple, but am learning PHP, Javascript as I go. I find it easier to learn using real examples than the contrived examples given online.

I am creating an attendance register page, based on selecting a class, then all members of that class ordered by Surname and Firstname.

The table row has it's id set, by PHP, as the record's mem_id, and contains just forename+" "+surname, and some checkboxes.

All this is working fine, but now I have been asked to add a link so that clicking on it brings up a modal containing related data for the person selected. The extra data is already in the $a_fetch array.

Have added a glyphicon link for every row and clicking it displays a modal alright, and by having a javascript function I know I can get the row index and row id

```
<tbody>
  <?php 
  while($g_fetch = $a_query->fetch_array()) {
    $checked = array();
    $memid = $g_fetch['mem_id'];
    $name = $g_fetch['firstname'].' '.$g_fetch['lastname'];
    $attendences = explode(",",$g_fetch['attend']);
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 12; $x++) {
      if ($attendences[$x]!="0") {
        $checked[$x] = 'checked = "checked"';
       }
      else $checked[$x] = '';
      } 
    echo "<tr id='".$memid."'>"; 
    echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><div id='".$memid."' class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' onclick='getId(this.id)' style='cursor:pointer' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalCentre'></div>";
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 12; $y++) {
      echo '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  value = "" '.$checked[$y].'></td>';
    } 
   }     
  unset($checked);
  unset($attendences);
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am at a loss as how to proceed - is it even possible to pass data to the modal to display related data?

If it is would I need to run a new query (SELECT), or as the row is the same index as the data in the $A_fetch, and the row id has the correct mem_id is it possible to get the data from the existing $a_fetch array using either of those, or would I need to run a new SELECT?

Many thanks

Comment: How is the modal loaded? Asynchronously using another php file?
A tip now in php we use the PDO object for connections and operations to the db.

Comment: It is a bootstrap modal, that is part of the same php page. When I've learned a bit more about PHP  I'll start looking at PDO. At least I'm not using the old MySQL syntax :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to provide data to the modal - and (in my opinion) it depends on how much data you need to pass to your modal and how many rows you have.

I want to describe you two ways:

### Light+Easier Solution

If you don't want to display a lot of data and you have just a few rows.
The idea is to add the data directly to each div.glyphicon (as `data` attributes) and then use it in the modal

In your foreach add it to your model like that:

```
<div id='".$memid."' class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' onclick='getId(this.id)' style='cursor:pointer' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalCentre' data-link='".$g_fetch['additional_link'] ."' data-moreInfo='".$g_fetch['moreInfo']."'></div>
```

You haven't posted the modal's HTML or your JS code, but you wrote you are using bootstrap, so stick to 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content
and fetch/set the relevant data (related clicked glyphicon) as it's described.

### More complex solution

For more data / more rows. The additional data is not provided in the inital loaded HTML page - Therefore not all data needs to be loaded in the beginning.
Instead the additional data is loaded via `ajax` when clicking on one row.

For that you need to provide an additional endpoint (php) which provides the modal content for one row.

Check out second answer in [Bootstrap 3 - How to load content in modal body via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663555/bootstrap-3-how-to-load-content-in-modal-body-via-ajax)

Basically you have a php file (e.g. getAdditionalData.php)
In this file you access the mem_id via GET

```
$mem_id = $_GET['mem_id'];
```

fetch the additional data from database
and print/render out the modal content (full `html` like in the second answer)

And in JS (inital page) you load the modal content `onClick` (fetched from php with provided `mem_id` as parameter)

```
var clicked = $(e.relatedTarget);
$(this).find(".modal-body").load("%PATH%/getAdditionalData.php?mem_id="+clicked.attr("id"));
```

I hope it will help you solving your problem and if you need additional infos just let me know. There are more ways to archive your goal but I think this 2 possibilities are enough in the beginning :-)

Comment: Thanks - I have used the first, and it works perfectly