# Filter data via ajax and django

Tags: django, ajax, filter

Hello By sending the value received from the dropdown and sending it to the server via ajax, I filtered my data and sent the result to the template. However, I can see the result through the web developer tools in the response tab, but the result is not visible on the web page. What is the reason?

Comment: Post your Ajax, and template at least

Comment: Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72641311/19288316