# Bootstrap not loading external files

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know some people have posted this issue and I went through them but mine just doesn't work. Please let me know what I'm doing worn.

Main HMTL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Rotana Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>   

<a data-toggle="modal" href="external.html" data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

External File

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
              </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal

Comment: Thanks....I actually went through that article but now I read it for the second time and found the bug.