# Bootstrap 3 Modal Via Ajax Load(CodeIgniter)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am trying to make the Bootstrap3 modal to work via Ajax Load using CodeIgniter. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal) but it's still not working. It's so simple to use when I follow what's in the docs but I want it to be via ajax load just like what I did for bootstrap 2.3.2. I am trying to figure it out for a couple of days but with no luck.

Here's my code:

**View:(the one that triggers the modal)**

```
<li role="presentation">
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo $this->config->item('Ompty_URL'); ?>/edit" data-target="#myModal">Edit Information</a>
</li>
```

**Controller:**

```
function edit(){
   $this->load->view('system/modals/edit_form');
}
```

**View:(the content of my modal)**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><div class="te"></div></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: hey you didn't change modal id to terms ,please apply that

Comment: My bad! I already edited my code. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Your modal wrappers `id` doesn't match your links `data-target`.

Change:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

to:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="terms" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I already edited my code but with no luck. Still not working.

Comment: I've made an improvement. My modal is showing but the CSS is a mess. The modal is not centered and I can't click it.

Comment: That sounds like it would have to be put in a completely different question as there are multiple different possibilities as to why that would happen.