# Show bootstrap modal when click on href Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

How can I show modal with dynamic content from database in Laravel?

my view:

```
<li><a href="{!! action('TestsController@show', $test->slug) !!}">{!! $test->test_name !!} </a></li>
```

my model:

```
public function show($slug)
    {
      $test = Test::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
      return view('tests.show', compact('test'));
    }
```

This modal I want to show on active page instead of creating new view. I guess it could be done with `return view()->with` but can not implement it.

Comment: You can do that with AJAX. To load your data but not refreshing the page.

Comment: Posible duplicate, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this trick if you want.

**in your controller:**

```
public function show($slug)
    {
      $test = Test::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
      return view('tests.show', compact('test'));
    }
```

**and in your view:**

```
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModal"></li>

<div class="modal fade" id="yourModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{$test->someTitle}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{$test->someField}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then if you have multiple data to get, you just have to use a `foreach`. For example:

**controller**

```
public function show()
    {
      $test = Test::all();
      return view('tests.show', compact('test'));
    }
```

**view:**

```
    @foreach ($test as $t)
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModal{{$t->id}}"></li>
    @endforeach

@foreach ($test as $t)    
    <div class="modal fade" id="yourModal{{$t->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{$t->someTitle}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            {{$t->someField}}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Nice and clean solution, works perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.