# FullCalendar list day's events modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar 2.4. I have an application that has the following specific parameters:

Monthly View only.
allDay events only.
No reoccurring events.
No multiple day events.

I have it working the way that I want, except for one feature. When someone clicks on an event, I have it pop up the title/description of the event with buttons to Edit or Delete the event. If you click on Edit, it pops up the edit form, and so forth.

The one thing that I'd like to add is a button that says "Reorder". I want it to popup (modal like "Edit" is or possibly another option) a list of all the events for that day (the day the original single event was on). I'm using a jQuery sortable list so they can change the order of the events by dragging/dropping. There will be a save button to save the new order. I'm not wanting to popup the reorder list on dayClick because I have an Add Event form that pops up then.

I have it all worked out EXCEPT getting the list of events for that day to display and be accessible (so I can reference the event id for later saving to MySQL where the calendar is stored).

It's not a big database, so I don't mind a round trip for data if that's the best way.  I'm just missing method and syntax.

I'm an experienced programmer but only been doing PHP for a few years and JQuery just this year.

I wouldn't mind doing the same thing with the Bubble that pops up when you click the +More link on a day...if I could figure out how to create a sortable list in it. I'm open to alternative ways of doing this if I'm missing a better way.

I've scoured Google and stackoverflow. I've found some similar situations but no cigar.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do. Do you just want to popup the list of events in day X and being able to reorder them (the way you want, by dragging) and then save?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. I have it worked out, but I'm having trouble getting the list of events to show up in the popup. I have a custom sort field that I'm using eventOrder with so the events can be ordered as the user wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would popup a modal (with ajax loaded content)

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    /* ... options ... */
    dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view ) {
        // some info in console
        console.log('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
        console.log('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        console.log('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // Here you load the modal
        $('#ajax_modal').load('nestable_list.php', {event_date: date.format()}, function(){
            $('#ajax_modal').modal();
        });
    },
    /* ... other options ... */
});
```

with a [nestable list](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) and the button save. In this file you will require you core php files with DB connection, so that you create your list and initialise the plugin.
My remote php file for modal content is like this:

```
<?php $date_str = $_GET['event_date'];
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_str)); //format the way you need
$res = $db->query("SELECT event_id, title FROM events_table WHERE event_date = '$date' ORDER BY index");
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close close-icon-medium" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="dd" id="nestable">
        <ol class="dd-list">
        <?php foreach($res AS $row) : ?>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="<?=$row['event_id']?>">
                <div class="dd-handle"><?=$row['title']?></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-sm save" type="button"> Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

You can also add your javascript at bottom of php file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nestable').nestable({ /* options here */});
    $('.save').on('click', function(){
        // loop over li elements and save index with ajax to another file.
        // close modal
        // you are done here
    });
});
```

Once the list is ordered and the save button clicked, you update each event with the current selected index (add event_index column in DB), and then refresh the calendar page. With

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
```

NB event index field will be default 0 and then 1 to n in each day, this will allow to fetch both unordered and ordered events in the wanted way. (add "ORDER BY event_index" to your query). Add ORDER BY to the query that fatches events from DB

Comment: I understand how to do that part. I'm having trouble with the "ajax loaded content" that you mention. I haven't been able to get the day's events loaded in the popup modal.

Comment: Are you able to get the selected day date?
Check this for loading content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal

Comment: I'm sure that the selected day date is in the event information that I'm first displaying. I checked that link and it's for remote loading of content. I'm just loading from the current calendar I'm displaying.

Comment: Check my post, I added few info from my code. Hope it helps

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I'm going to give that a whirl! I'll post back here when completed.

Comment: Ok. I need some clarification...I'm still new at ajax and jquery. I'm still in the same boat...I'm not getting the events loaded in the popup. When you say "My remote php file for modal content", are you referring to the "nestable_list.php" file referenced in your popup modal example?

Comment: Yeah, you should create a nestable_list.php file and add code in my post, then in you DOM add a div for modal <div id="modal_ajax" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="basic" style="display: none;"></div>

Comment: It's all working EXCEPT populating the div with the list of events. I'm just looking to display the event title, but I also need the id and a custom field "sortorder" which I use to determine the order. I'm using FullCalendar, but I'm unclear on how to return more than one event. Is there a container for that? Do I need to make one or maybe an array? I can display one event...but I can't get a list.

Comment: In the modal, you don't have to care about events. When you click the day, you send via POST/GET the date and show the modal. In the modal you make a query to your DB, fetching all events in that day, and display them as list elements on which you will initialise your nestable plugin

Comment: That did it! I just need that little bit explained. Thank you my friend!