# trigger ASP.Net button Or call ASP.NET function using external JavaScript ".js" file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to ***Trigger ASP.Net button Or call ASP.NET function using external JavaScript ".js" file***.

I am currently using the following code but it failed.

```js
function setXMLAnnotationsData(xmlAnnotData) {
                debugger;

        document.getElementById('txtAnnotationsXMLData').value = xmlAnnotData;
        var txtAnnotationsXMLData = window.parent.frames[2].document.getElementById('txtAnnotationsXMLData');
        if (txtAnnotationsXMLData) {
            txtAnnotationsXMLData.value = xmlAnnotData;
        }



        window.parent.frames[2].document.getElementById('txtHHNo').value = window.parent.document.getElementById("txtHHNO").value;



        var btnSaveRecord = window.parent.frames[2].document.getElementById('btnSaveRecord');
        if (btnSaveRecord) {
            btnSaveRecord.click(); //**Here I want to Perform This click**
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/frmSaveAnnotation.aspx/test',
                data: { jsonData: "testing" },
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

        }
        var btnAntSearch = ObjTreePage.getElementById('btnAntSearch');
        if (btnAntSearch) {
            btnAntSearch.click();
            document.getElementById('<%= btnSaveRecord.ClientID %>').click();
        }
        return;
    }
```

**I am using button ID is btnSaveRecord in My ASPX file**

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: No any error but My cursor not came in onclick event

Comment: can you check the length of the button in `iframe` wither it is able to find that or else you can use the `jquery` equivalent of the code as `$('<IframeId/name>').contents().find('<buttonID>').click();` but you need to make sure the contents of the `iframe` are loaded before you call this code.

Comment: when I debug JavaScript on IE I found this exception **'btnSaveRecord' is undefined**. But this Javascript working fine on Framework 3.5 and currently, I am Upgraded my application in Framework 4.0

Comment: If `iframes` are not a necessity then you can also use the bootstrap's `modal` you would have a better control over them.

Comment: Can you give me one sample code for that I am not user-friendly with bootstrap

Comment: I used try catch in javascript and here I didn't get any exception but issue shown in ScriptResource.axd

Comment: take a look at [Bootstrap 3 remote Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387625/2417602)

Comment: ok i will try and get back to you